# OpenSearch Date Range Codes

Tags: opensearch

Trying to set OpenSearch Date Range Aggregation Slice by custom date ranges.  I have googled for an interpretation of the date codes used in the UX for creating these custom ranges.  I can not find a complete definition of how to encode these ranges.  I know what the letters mean (h,m,s,d,w,M,y,etc.) What I am trying to understand what these letters mean when placed into the structure of a custom range for example: `now-1w/w -> now-1d/d`.  Does the first clause mean 'from now to one week back, by week' The second 'from now to 1 day back by day'  The pattern I have entered does not seem to work...

[image: OpenSearch Date Range Example]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`now-1w/w -> now-1d/d` This means, now minus 1 week rounded off to the beginning of the week TO now minus 1 day rounded off to the beginning of the day.

`/w /h /d` are all rounding off.

Look here for further examples --> https://opensearch.org/docs/latest/field-types/date/#example-expressions